# Access data in chunked array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm dividing a large array in PHP with the function array_chunk, and then converting the result array to json with json_encode. My response is like this:

```
[["nombre","apellido","flor","animal","ciudad","cosa"],["nombre","apellido","flor","animal","ciudad","cosa"],["nombre","apellido","flor","animal","ciudad","cosa"]]
```

Now, I want to get that array of arrays via ajax, and put every item in a column of a table.

Normally, if I just get a single array, I do something like this:

```
//rest of the ajax function...
success: function(data) {
$("#resultados").append("<tr><td>"+data[0]+"</td><td>"+data[1]+"</td><td>"+data[2]+"</td><td>"+data[3]+"</td><td>"+data[4]+"</td><td>"+data[5]+"</td><td>"+data[6]+"</td><td>"+data[7]+"</td><td>"+data[8]+"</td><td>"+data[9]+"</td><td>"+data[10]+"</td></tr>");
}
```

Where "resultados" is the ID of a table row.

I want to put the data of each array in a different table, so how I can access the indexes of those arrays?

Comment: [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L1oyc2h2/) like this

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this

```
    //rest of the ajax function
    success: function(data){
        //we access first array and then inner
        $.each(data,function(index,value){
            // now we access inner arrays
            $.each(data[index],function(index2,value2){
                //here you do what you had to do
                //data[index][index2] equals value2
            });
        });
    }
```